# Angular Js: Simple unit test not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

**THE SITUATION:**

I am trying to set up unit test for my angular app. I have created a basic test angular app and wrote a simple unit test, but is not working as expected.

**THE APP:**

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] );

app.controller('InitCtrl', function( $scope, Person ) 
{
    $scope.test_person = Person.Person("Tom");
})

app.factory('Person', function(){
    return {
        Person: function(name){
            this.name = name;
            console.log ( name );
        }
    }               
})
```

**THE UNIT TEST:**

```
describe('Person', function () {

  var Person;
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function (_Person_) {
    Person = _Person_;
  }));

  describe('Constructor', function () {

    it('assigns a name', function () {
      expect(new Person('Ben')).to.have.property('name', 'Ben');
    });

  });

});
```

**THE ERROR MESSAGE:**

When i run the test i get the actual error message:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Person "before each" hook: workFn for "assigns a name" FAILED
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
```

**THE ATTEMPTS:**

I have tried with different sintax as:

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp' );
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.

**THE QUESTION:**

What is wrong in this simple test?
There is something missing in the app, or something wrong in the test?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you did not load your app.js in your [karma configuration file](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/configuration-file.html):

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',    
        files: [
            '../../path/to/app.js',
         //...
```

Comment: Thank you. It was missing that indeed. I still get an error, but at least the test is run: Person Constructor assigns a name FAILED
 TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Person('Ben')')